# Change default windows folder icons - their shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, shortcuts

I've managed to follow the instructions here to change the default folder icons for all folders (since hey're super boring and I don't want to change each folder icon manually):

[https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-change-default-folder-icons-in-windows/#:~:text=Changing%20these%20individual%20folder%20icons,another%20icon%20of%20your%20choice](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-change-default-folder-icons-in-windows/#:%7E:text=Changing%20these%20individual%20folder%20icons,another%20icon%20of%20your%20choice).

But, the problem is, the "shortcuts" of the folders will still look unchanged. What should I do so that the shortcuts also change?

Thank you.

Best wishes,

Comment: Are you referring to the small overlay added on top of the desktop icons of shortcuts?

Comment: Hi. I actually found out what to do. I meant the shortcuts  of folders and large folders would would show thumbnails wouldn't show the new icon I wanted to use following the above steps, but, well, the thumbnail version of the default folders. So I followed the steps below to stop thumbnail view for folders (but not files) using below guide:


https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-folder-thumbnails-without-disabling-thumbnail-preview-for-files/